# distinct unordered dynamic column in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

query:

```
let result = datatable(MyString:string)
[
'{"X": "xyz", "Y": "xyz", "Z": "xyz", "prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", "prop3": "value3"}',
'{"Y": "xyz", "X": "xyz", "Z": "xyz", "prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", "prop3": "value3"}'
];
result
| distinct *
```

result is

```
{"X": "xyz", "Y": "xyz", "Z": "xyz", "prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", "prop3": "value3"}
{"Y": "xyz", "X": "xyz", "Z": "xyz", "prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", "prop3": "value3"}
```

is there any operation in kusto to make the result be ordered by key and then get the distinct to be the result like:

```
{"prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", "prop3": "value3", "X": "xyz", "Y": "xyz", "Z": "xyz"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `dynamic_to_json()` to sort the keys in the JSON (see details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dynamic-to-json-function)) - note that the key "X" comes before "prop1", because the uppercase chars comes before lowercase chars.

This is what the correct query looks like:

```
let result = datatable(MyString:string)
[
    '{"X": "xyz", "Y": "xyz", "Z": "xyz", "prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", "prop3": "value3"}',
    '{"Y": "xyz", "X": "xyz", "Z": "xyz", "prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", "prop3": "value3"}'
];
result
| extend MyString = tostring(dynamic_to_json(todynamic(MyString)))
| distinct *
```

Result:

| MyString |
| --- |
| {"X":"xyz","Y":"xyz","Z":"xyz","prop1":"value1","prop2":"value2","prop3":"value3"} |

Note: for query efficiency, it's better to store JSONs as `dynamic` columns and not as `string` columns. Here's how:

```
let result = datatable(MyJSON:dynamic) [
    dynamic({'a': {'b': {'c': 0.0, 'd': 4.0}, 'e': {'f': {'g': 0.0, 'h': 1.0}}}}),
    dynamic({'a': {'e': {'f': {'g': 0.0, 'h': 1.0}}, 'b': {'c': 0.0, 'd': 4.0}}})
];
result
| extend MyJSON = dynamic_to_json(MyJSON)
| distinct *
```

Comment: i tried on multi column for example: 
let result = datatable(MyJSON:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({'a': "{'b': {'c': 0.0, 'd': 4.0}, 'e': {'f': {'g': 0.0, 'h': 1.0}}}"}),
    dynamic({'a': "{'e': {'f': {'g': 0.0, 'g': 1.0}}, 'b': {'c': 0.0, 'd': 4.0}}}"})
];
result
| extend MyJSON = dynamic_to_json(MyJSON)
| distinct *
the solution is not correct
any adjustment?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I put extra quotes. I've updated the answer to have the JSONs in correct format, and now everything works.